# With Aurelia, is there a way to store data clientside for reuse between view classes?

Tags: aurelia

I have some data that is accessed between multiple views.  If there any want to share that? In Angular, I was able to store stuff on a rootscope or parent controller, then it became available to all sub-views/controllers.

I see no reason to continually fetch them.

Comment: http://hobbit-on-aurelia.net/appstate/

Comment: http://patrickwalters.net/my-best-practices-in-aurelia/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Services/classes are created as singletons (unless you tell the DI otherwise, I believe) so use a service class/module and inject it into your view controllers.

Then the service class can use internal, cached data or it can depend on, say, the http module and fetch data as needed.

EDIT: Added a bit of a sample:

I doubt this will work directly but it should give the basic idea.

Global service "someGlobalStuff.js":

```
import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {HttpClient} from 'aurelia-http-client';

@inject(HttpClient)
export class SomeGlobalStuff {

    constructor(http) {
        this.http = http;
    }

    getSomethingVital() {
        if (this.somethingVital) {
            return Promise.resolve(this.somethingVital)
        } else {
            // Do something with the HTTP client that will get the 
            // required stuff and return a promise
            return this.http.get(blah blah blah)
                .then(r => {
                    this.somethingVital = r;
                    return r; // 
                });
        }       
    }
}
```

And something that uses it:

```
import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {SomeGlobalStuff} from 'someGlobalStuff';

@inject(SomeGlobalStuff)
export class DataManager {

    constructor(someGlobalStuff) {
        this.globalStuff = someGlobalStuff;
    }

    doSomething() {
        this.globalStuff.getSomethingVital()
            .then(v => { 
                // Do something with it
            })      
    }
}
```

Comment: The documentation is not clear at all. :) I'll see what I can interpret from it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Don't think the docs are that bad but I've added a bit more of an explanation/sample.

Comment: So multiple calls to `getSomethingVital` will resolve the same promise?

Comment: Technically it will resolve a new Promise each time but will only need to go off to the server once. In reality you could, feasibly, refer to globalStuff.somethingVital directly so long as you KNOW that it has been retrieved once and fully resolved. But that would go against the point of the promises.